# Invalid URL error in Appwrite and react +vite application

Tags: reactjs, url, vite, appwrite

[1][I am getting invalid url error in an appwrite and react + vite website

I have tried `console.log(conf.appwriteUrl)` to check if url and ProjectID is passing on correctly(they are)  and there are no typo in the url and project id
]
here is an image of my code :

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6QE.png)

Error says "Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL"
and here is an image of an error:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoNmc.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaqz8.png

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6QE.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHwbC.png

Comment: Please do **not** post images of code - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The Appwrite SDK accepts a `string` type as the parameter in the `client.setEndpoint` function, not the `URL` type. An example of this is:

```js
client
    .setEndpoint('https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1')
    .setProject('[PROJECT-ID]');
```

Can you check if your type is set correctly in the `conf.js` file? This might be causing an error cirumstantially.

Additionally, it would help to recheck if the right endpoint has been copied from the Appwrite Console as well.

Comment: Endpoints are set to the string only u can see that in 3rd image above

Answer (score 1):

Don't use quotes in your .env.local file.
Working example:

```
VITE_APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID = 111111111111111111111
VITE_APPWRITE_URL = https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1
```

Answer (score 0):

What URL are you using? It is the best to copy paste the server endpoint from the project settings page.

Comment: yeah i have copy pasted server url and project id from the appwrite project setting

Answer (score 0):

found the error , i was wraping url in two strings by mistake it was something like this "'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1'"

but now a new error has appeared saying :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1;/account' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.